# Variable not defined MongoDB $function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregation

Ok I am confused. I am trying to find documents using the $function operator as described here: [S_function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/#exp._S_function).

My model:

```
const newsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
news_id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    unique: true,
    index: true
},
created_at: { type: String, default: Date.now().toString() },
updated_at: { type: String, default: Date.now().toString() },
Company_id: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}],
Stock_id: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}],
newsItem: {
    date: {type: String},
    title: { type: String },
    summary: { type: String },
    url: { type: String, unique: true },
    content: { type: String }
}
};
```

My code attempt:

```
newsModel.aggregate([
        {$match: {$function: {
            body: matchArrToArr(matchArr, Company_id),
            args: [ "$Company_id" ],
            lang: "js"
         }}}
    ])
```

matchArr is a variable I pass in from the surrounding function and *Company_id* is supposed to be the array '*Company_id*' from the news document. However when I execute the function, the error '*Company_id is not defined*' is returned. Which makes sense, as I dont define it but how do I get the *Company_id* field into the function.

I also tried *find($expr:{$function:...* with the same result and *$where:...* with *this.Company_id*. First case same error. Second case *'this'* has the state of my calling JS function and not the DB document.

What I am actually trying to do: I want to return all documents, where one of the ids in the Company_id array matches one of the ids I pass in. If there is a nicer aggregate way without $function, I am open to that. But I also want to understand what I am doing wrong with my $function expression.

Thanks!

Comment: Function declaration and function invocation are two different this. You need to define a function not invoke it. MongoDB will invoke the function you passed it as an argument to `body` property. Do not call `matchArrToArr` function. Replace it with function definition.

Comment: Update the question with your attempt. If still not working I will help u.

Comment: Omg yes you are completely right, stupid me. Maybe my 3 days no food is showing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```js
let someCompany_id = "60278ce8b370ff29b83226e7";

db.news.find(
    {
        $expr: {
            $function: {
                body: function(company_ids, someCompany_id) {
                    let _ids= company_ids.map(company_id => company_id.valueOf());
                    return _ids.includes(someCompany_id);
                },
                args: ["$company_id", someCompany_id],
                lang: "js"
            }
        }
    }
)
```

But this can be done easily like this:

```js
db.news.find({ 
    company_id: {
        $in: [someCompany_id]
    }
});
```

So why do you want to pass function?

Comment: Yes I was calling instead of passing the function. As usual when I am stuck it is the dumbest of mistakes. The reason I cannot just do a simple find is that both input and match IDs are arrays and I want a match if just one of them matches. So [someId1,someId2] and [someId2, someId3] should return true,